# Removed Empathy icon from panel, how do I add it back?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, gnome-panel, empathy

I installed Ubuntu 10.04 and got Empathy IM client configured. The icon on the panel next to the clock, n/w was not functioning as expected, so I accidentally removed it from the panel. Now I am unable to see the icon to show my contacts online. How do I add it back to the panel?

Answer (score 3):

[Colin's answer](https://superuser.com/a/137735/167207) is correct. For a more detailed walk-through, right-click on your panel, and select the Add to Panel option. In the dialog that comes up, scroll down to the Indicator Applet (not to be confused with Indicator Applet Session), and select that. Now you will have the Envelope icon showing when you get a message again. The closely related Indicator Applet Session is the tool that lets you select your messaging status from the panel.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's `indicator-applet` you have removed, is there something by that name or similar in the Add to Panel menu?